# Correct wrong date of different time zones (browser vs. server)

Tags: javascript

I just realized that my code has a huge issue. I have a input where the user writes a date `vm.startDate`.

I need to make the request using this date in milisseconds to `url + startDate`.

The API server is hosted on UCT +2 and I'm on the browser in UCT+0 so I'm generating the wrong date in milisseconds (the hour is wrong when i checked ms to date online).

How can I solve this issue? Am I supposed to add hour based where the server is deployed?

```
 // By default select the today's date
var todayDate = new Date();
var day = todayDate.getDate();
var month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = todayDate.getFullYear();

vm.startDate = day + "." + month + "." + year; // assign default date

$scope.$watch("vm.startDate", function() {
    console.log(vm.startDate);   

    if(vm.startDate != null) {
        // Concat 00:00:00 time
        var startDate = vm.startDate.split(".");
        startDate = new Date(startDate[2], startDate[1] - 1, startDate[0]);
        startDate = startDate.getTime(); // Time in ms
        console.log("Time in ms: " + startDate);
        // Get File In Data
        $http.get(url + startDate).then(..... Stuff) 


   }
```

Please help me

Comment: so convert the date to UTC and adjust.

Comment: Please don't mark questions as 'urgent' - everyone on Stack Overflow is a volunteer, and it's unfair to expect your question to be prioritized over anyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for this issue is:

> Work with *UTC* and make **transform only on the presentational layer** (the frontend)

You have to **send always UTC timestamp**, when a browser with different locale need to render it, transform it to reflect the browser's timezone.

Library such [MomentJS](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment-timezone/01-using-timezones/05-default-timezone/) do it by default using the browser timezone:

> By default, moment objects are created in the local time zone.

Comment: I personally use new Date().getTime(), this will return a UTC in milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970

Comment: That's what I am already using `startDate = startDate.getTime(); // Time in ms`

Comment: In fact this is right, all you have to do is to record in the backend exactly the same UTC. Then when you get the UTC from your server. Then when you fetch the data there are various way of converting it to local time, as appending 'UTC' to the string before converting it to a date: `new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');`

Comment: You do not have to hardcode it, you have to send an UTC, and you have to save THE SAME UTC, if you were saving the integer in milliseconds, this is still the same integer. When showing in the frontend both Date() or MomentJs will add the right value